# Evaluating the score function at the MLEs for an lme model in nlme and R

Tags: r, nlme

As a sanity check for later  goals, I am trying to understand how components of an lme object are related. I am trying to evaluate the score functions at the MLEs obtained from a lme object created using gamm to check that they are equal to zero. I've provided a minimal working example. My score functions were obtained from equation (7) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.04911.pdf.

```
library(lme4)
library(mgcv)
library(lasso2) # for Prostate data set
data(Prostate)

model = gamm(lpsa ~lcavol + s(lweight), data=Prostate)$lme
```

Here I compute the objects needed to evaluate the score functions

```
X = model.matrix(formula(model), data=model$data)
YminXbeta = c(model$data$y - X %*% fixed.effects(model))
varcomps = VarCorr(model)
varcomps = as.numeric(varcomps[nrow(varcomps) - (1:0),1])
Sigmainv = solve(extract.lme.cov2(model, data=model$data)$V)
Sigmainvsq = Sigmainv %*% Sigmainv

ZVZT = (model$data$Xr %*% (getVarCov(model, 
 type='random.effects')/varcomps[1]) %*% t(model$data$Xr))
SigmainvZVZT = Sigmainv %*% ZVZT
SigmainvZVZTsq = SigmainvZVZT %*% SigmainvZVZT
```

Now I evaluate the scores at the MLEs

```
# the scores
# the score for the mean parameter
sbeta = t(X) %*% Sigmainv %*% YminXbeta
#                 [,1]
# X(Intercept)    5.329071e-14
# Xlcavol         1.190159e-13
# Xs(lweight)Fx1 -1.110223e-15

# the score for the error variance parameter
ssigmasq = (-sum(diag(Sigmainv)) + YminXbeta %*% Sigmainvsq %*% 
YminXbeta)/2
# 3.664974e-08

# the score for the random effect parameter
stausq = (-sum(diag(SigmainvZVZT)) + YminXbeta %*% SigmainvZVZT 
%*% Sigmainv %*% YminXbeta)/2
# -7.507903
```

Note that the random effects variance component is close to zero

```
varcomps[1] # 2.665509e-09
```

but I'm not sure that would make the derivative nonzero.

Why is the score function for the variance component term not close to zero? Am I making a mistake or misunderstand what the objects in the lme object are?